# ApplicationRef.tick vs setTimeout

Tags: angular

I have this situation in my angular app that I have to do

```
...                     // change @input of a component
setTimeout(() => {      // wait for the component to process the change
    ...                 // do stuff
});
```

Now I noticed that I can get the same result if I use the `tick` function from `ApplicationRef`

```
this.appRef.tick();
```

This looks like a better (more angular) way.

So my question is will both solution always have the same outcome. Because if it does, I would say that `setTimeout` is easier because you don't have to inject the ApplicationRef into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same:

```
setTimeout(()=> {});
```

just emulates an async event that Angular picks up to execute Change Detection over the current Component.
You can consider it the same as this use of [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

```
_changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
```

while your

```
this.appRef.tick();
```

would check the entire application and all the components currently loaded in your View tree, instead of the single component you are working with.

I would say with an app with many components loaded at the same time setTimeout should be faster than appRef.tick but i think the speed difference usually lies in the milliseconds if not less.

Outside of this difference, everything else stays the same